# MPEG-DASH validator reporting timing errors

Tags: validation, mp4, h.264, mpeg-dash

My problem could be related to any of a couple of components in my setup so I'm just going to describe the whole thing here.

I'm grabbing h.264 NAL packets from a blackmagic h.264 Pro Recorder, and packing them into mp4 containers for DASH myself.  My goal is to set up a live MPEG-DASH stream from the recorder.

My mp4 init and segment files seem ok (I can open them using MP4Explorer and confirm that the various fields have been set up the way I want), and my mpd file passes validation using the validator at http://dashif.org/conformance.html.

I'm serving the DASH stream from an IIS server and trying to validate it using that same validator, and I get the following errors:

```
WARNING: unknown mvex atom 'trep'
WARNING: unknown/unexpected atom 'meta'
tfdt base media decode time 2.816000 not equal to accumulated decode time 0.000000 for track 1 for the first fragment of the movie. This software does not handle incomplete presentations. Applying correction.
### error: 
### tfdt base media decode time 4.816000 not equal to accumulated decode time 6.656000 for track 1 for sequence_number 2 (fragment absolute count 2)
### error: 
### tfdt base media decode time 6.816000 not equal to accumulated decode time 12.416000 for track 1 for sequence_number 3 (fragment absolute count 3)
### error: 
### tfdt base media decode time 8.816000 not equal to accumulated decode time 20.096000 for track 1 for sequence_number 4 (fragment absolute count 4)
### error: 
### tfdt base media decode time 10.816000 not equal to accumulated decode time 29.696000 for track 1 for sequence_number 5 (fragment absolute count 5)
### error: 
### tfdt base media decode time 12.816000 not equal to accumulated decode time 41.216000 for track 1 for sequence_number 6 (fragment absolute count 6)
### error: 
### tfdt base media decode time 14.816000 not equal to accumulated decode time 54.656000 for track 1 for sequence_number 7 (fragment absolute count 7)

...more of the same, and finally...

### error: 
### Buffer underrun conformance error: first (and only one reported here) for sample 1 of run 1 of track fragment 1 of fragment 1 of track id 1 (sample absolute file offset 3835, fragment absolute file offset 863, bandwidth: 5000)
```

So I suspect I'm either not filling in my tfdt time fields correctly, or I'm not setting up my DASH stream properly.  I've compared my files with other mp4s and it seems like the time field should increase linearly as mine do (I may be misunderstanding the spec: ISO/IEC 14496-12).  Anyone out there with knowledge of both h.264 and DASH, who could help me figure this out?

My mpd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MPD 
    availabilityStartTime="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" 
    publishTime="2016-07-14T13:59:43Z" 
    maxSegmentDuration="PT2S" 
    minBufferTime="PT1S" 
    minimumUpdatePeriod="P100Y" 
    profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
    timeShiftBufferDepth="PT1M" 
    type="dynamic" 
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011">

    <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
        <Title>BLACKMAGIC DASH</Title>
    </ProgramInformation>

<Period id="p0" start="PT0S">
    <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="1920" maxHeight="1080" maxFrameRate="60" par="16:9" lang="und">
        <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video" />
        <!--ContentComponent id="2" contentType="audio" /-->
        <Representation id="V300" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc3.640028,mp4a.40.2" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="60" sar="1:1" audioSamplingRate="48000" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="5000">
            <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" media="$RepresentationID$/$Number$.m4s" startNumber="0" duration="2000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4"/>
        </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
</Period>

</MPD>
```

I can provide more info (and the link to the DASH stream) on request.